# get time of forwarded events with Get-winevent?

Tags: events, powershell

Good day.
I'm trying to filter logs with get-winevent. When I working with local logs as security, system etc. all is ok. StartTime work correctly.

```
$yesterday = (get-date) - (new-timespan -day 1) 
$a = get-winevent -FilterHashTable @{LogName='system'; StartTime=$yesterday}
```

When I try to use this command with "forwarded events" there is error: "Get-WinEvent : No events were found that match the specified selection criteria." Problem with "StartTime" and "EndTime" only.

Anyone knew where is the problem?

Comment: Does [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/winserverpowershell/thread/33422df3-8a0d-4a9e-b2e4-236486d3af22) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these types of logs you need to use an xpath query, which is complicated.

```
$query=@"
<QueryList>
  <Query Id='0' Path='Microsoft-Windows-Dhcp-Client/Admin'>
    <Select Path='Microsoft-Windows-Dhcp-Client/Admin'>*[System[TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 2592000000]]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
"@

get-winevent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-Dhcp-Client/Admin -FilterXPath $query
```

I don't have anything in ForwardedEvents so I used a different log. The best thing to do is use EventViewer to build your query then copy and paste the XML. You'll most likely need to fiddle with quote characters.